# About publishing via terminal (turtlebot)

Tags: ros, turtlebot, topic, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I was trying to move the turtlebot via terminal and my surprise was that this instruction is not moving the robot

```
$ rostopic pub -r 10 /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist  '{linear:  {x: 0.1, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}, angular: {x: 0.0,y: 0.0,z: 0.0}}'
```

Before using this instrucction I used:

> $ roscore 
> >
> >  $ roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch

So I think that maybe its a good idea try to use the name of the turtlebot before /cmd_vel but there is no turtlebot_node on the list of obtained using rosnode.

(with the teleop key works fine)

What can I do?

Thanks beforehand!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203011/about-publishing-via-terminal-(turtlebot)/) by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2015-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using the topic `/mobile_base/commands/velocity` solved the problem

---

Originally posted by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) with karma: 82 on 2015-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0